# Adding Bicarb to Sparkling Water

Tags: acid-base

This may seem a trivial request of mine, but it is a major part of my health regime,

I add Bicarb (Sodium Bicarbonate - NaHCO3) to Sparkling Water (H2O + CO2 (bubbles) + a weak solution of Carbonic Acid - H2CO3)

There is an effervescent reaction.
But I cannot find an explanation of this - using chemical formulae - online.

I do this a lot of this for health reasons - with the approval of my GP.
It changes my pH levels from acidic to alkaline/neutral.

So I'd like to know the gas that is released, and the residual solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Virtually any powder** added to sparkling water, or seltzer, club soda or any other carbonated drink cause outgassing by [nucleating](https://sustainable-nano.com/2018/09/27/nucleation/) bubbles of $\ce{CO2}$. See [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/47071/what-causes-soda-to-fizz-and-how-can-it-be-stopped) and [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/243148/why-rough-surfaces-promote-nucleation-of-co2-in-carbonated-drinks) Stack Exchange, and [this talk on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S9H3_sMheKk).

Comment: "talk on YouYube" and not some dozen questions about that *here*?

Comment: Thank you. So the gas released is Carbon Dioxide. Is the residual solution Sodium bicarbonate dissolved in water or is there a chemical reaction ?

Comment: It's a mixture of dissolved solids and dissolved gases, no reaction is likely. BTW, Your "formula" reminded me of T. Edison's boyhood exploit: he "once persuaded a boy employed by the family to swallow a large quantity of Seidlitz powders in the belief that the gases generated would enable him to fly. The awful agonies of the victim attracted attention..." https://www.heritage-history.com/index.php?c=read&author=meadowcroft&book=edison&story=boyhood It seems you're close to reinventing that powder ;-)